# Find numerical relationship between $~\ I_{1} ~$ and $~\ I_{2}~$.

Tags: calculus, integration

> Let $~\ f(x)\in C[0,1]\searrow, \lambda \in (0,1),\ I_{1}=\int^{\lambda}_{0}f(x)dx,\ I_{2}=\lambda\int^{1}_{0}f(x)dx,~$ find  numerical relationship between $~\ I_{1} ~$ and $~\  I_{2}~$

How to solve the question?
my steps like this:

let $$\ I_{1}-I_{2}=\int^{\lambda}_{0}f(x)dx-\lambda\int^{1}_{0}f(x)dx=(1-\lambda)\int^{\lambda}_{0}f(x)dx-\lambda\int^{1}_{\lambda}f(x)dx=g(\lambda)
\\
g'=-\int^{\lambda}_{0}f(x)dx+(1-\lambda)f(\lambda)-\int^{1}_{\lambda}f(x)dx+\lambda f(\lambda)=f(\lambda)-\int^{1}_{0}f(x)dx
$$
I tried to find the root $g'=0$ but failed.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $\frac{1}{\lambda} \int_0^\lambda f(x)\; dx$ is the average value of $f$ on the interval $[0,\lambda]$.  How does that relate to the average over $[0,1]$?

Further hint: the relationship is an inequality, not an equation.

Comment: Not if $f$ is decreasing (which was part of the problem until somebody edited it out).

Answer (score 0):

$I_1=\int_0^{1} f(y\lambda) \lambda \, dy$ by the substitution $y=\frac x {\lambda}$. Since $f(y\lambda)  \geq f(y)$ we get $I_1 \geq \lambda \int_0^{1} f(y)\, dy = I_2$.